# Can information be read on public blockchain even if you arent the owner?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, distributed

Let's imagine I write information on a public blockchain like Ethereum, in plain text. This information could be a transaction or even a smart contract that I deployed. Can another user read this information in the blockchain? As we are talking about a public network I guess this information is available for everyone, right? And if that is, how? For example, can another user, with the block number or the transaction ID go to etherscan and in same way read the code of my smart contract? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plain code no, like the solidity source code. But it's possibile to "decompile" the ABI and get a "raw" version of your code.
You can upload the source code then verify the smart contract on the scanner (for eth [etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io)), this process enforce the "credibility" of your contract.

Answer (score 0):

Public data is by definition public. It means everybody can read it.

You can read the data by using a blockchain explorer or reading the data directly from your Ethereum node.

While binary data is always public, human-readable data often needs an [ABI file](https://www.quicknode.com/guides/solidity/what-is-an-abi). With the ABI file, [Ethereum JSON-RPC access](https://ethereumnodes.com/) you can use a library like Web3.js or Web3.py to read the data easily.

Comment: So you mean that an external user will need the ABI file and a connection to the blockchain I have my deployed contract to be able to read, for example, the source code of my contract?

Comment: The source code of your contract is not important, because you can always reverse engineering deployed bytecode.

Comment: Yes but I mean, not just the source code of a smart contract but also for example, the data of a transaction, right?

Comment: Why do you think someone could not read data if they have it on their computer?